# Interfaces - property defined in a base class

Tags: c#, oop

I can guarantee that all classes derived from my **ICharacter** interface will also inherit from **MonoBehaviour** class. The **MonoBehaviour** class has a property **transform**.

However the following obviously fails, because the interface doesn't implement the **transform** property:

```
ICharacter character;
var t = character.transform;
```

Is it possible to make the above work, without making another parent class that will inherit from **MonoBehaviour** (i.e. MyCharacter : Character : MonoBehaviour)? I tried adding a **transform** property to the interface, but it then hides the property of the parent class.

Basically I need to somehow call a property of a base class using an interface.

Making a base class for my characters seems feasible, but I cannot guarantee that it will be possible to inherit all of them from the same **Character** class. However all of them will 100% be inherited from **MonoBehaviour** class.

Comment: If you want to make it a guarantee, make `MonoBehaviour` implement `IMonoBehaviour` and have `ICharacter` inherit `IMonoBehaviour`.

Comment: MohoBehaviour is a third-party class that I don't have access to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you expect all `ICharacter` types to have a `transform` member then that should be in the interface.

When a type implements an interface and a base class has a suitable member, that member doesn't need to be re-implemented; the base class member can be bound to the interface.

Additionally, you can explicitly implement the interface if you need to provide an implementation that is only exposed through the interface.

Comment: Great, thanks! It turned out that the base class had only a get property defined. I was getting a error because I defined both get and set properties in my interface. Removing the set property fixed the issue.